# How to properly run heat.exe tool to generate Wix code compatible with InstallScope='perUser'?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

We use Wix tool heat.exe for harvesting files when building MSI installer. The problem is that the XML generated by this tool is not compatible with per-user installation type. Is there a way to make it generate valid code, or is there XSLT that fixes already generated code?

Thanks!

Comment: Based on your question, I take it you know about `-t` switch of heat.exe, which allows you to run any XSLT against the generated XML? If so, and your question is only about whether there's a ready-made XSLT to tweak your XML to be PerUser-friendly, then I'm not aware about any. You'll have to create one yourself...

Comment: Thanks! And I'm quite done with the XSLT, except for several ICE64 errors on some [directory entries](http://pastebin.com/HaiJaCX6). As these entries are missing "Component" definition, I'm not sure where to add relevant "RemoveFolder" entries (here's the [example](http://pastebin.com/Z7L3nrag)).

Answer (score 0):

A per-user setup is defined via the [**ALLUSERS property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx) during installation or as specified in the Property table of the MSI itself. MSI components themselves have no encoding to set whether they support per-user or per-machine installations.

The changes applied to the MSI installation based on this rather dubious per-user / per-machine concept can be viewed in [this article explaining the issue of installation context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd765197(v=vs.85).aspx).

I find per-user installations more trouble than they are worth. Especially when you run into scenarios where some users favor per-machine installs and other users favor per-user installs. It gets complicated for upgrade scenarios quickly.